# rails : Using params in another action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 3 models, survey -> question -> answer they are related by has_many/belongs_to and nested_form.

I can get params in create(POST) action.

```
 "questions"=>{"11"=>{"answer"=>"40"}, "10"=>{"answer"=>"37"}, "9"=>{"answer"=>"31"}}
```

I want to show user's input in show(GET) action. Let's assume that u are taking online test. If u done it, u are going to submit form, and then web server returns result page with your input.

I thought that just save that hashes in create action and use them in show action. But searching google and stackoverflow, I realized that's not a good idea. How can I use that params in show action?

Comment: When you submit your form, do you persist the Question & Answers values in a DB?

Answer (score 0):

In the create action you're presumably saving the data in this param to the database, so why not just call it in the show action?

in the controller:

```
@questions = Question.all
```

in the view:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <h4><%= question.content %></h4>
    <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
      <%= answer.content %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```